# Unable to run appimages from desktop Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, appimage

I, just a few days ago upgraded from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, overall no issues, however I am now unable to run appimages that are on my desktop by double clicking them. I have FUSE installed and the permissions set, I can even get them to run when I have the desktop folder open in the file manager but when I double click them on the desktop it self nothing happens. I am additionally able to run the appimages directly from the desktop if I right click and select run as program. i am kind stumped here and can not for the life of me get them to run from the desktop by double clicking like I did before. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:#1

I have FUSE2 2.9.9.5ubuntu3 which apt tells me is the newest version

Comment: Which version of FUSE do you have installed? AppImage needs Fuse2, which is not part of the installation for Ubuntu 22.04. It comes with Fuse3.
Fuse2 can be installed from the sources running `sudo apt install libfuse2`.

Comment: I do have the newest version of FUSE2 already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've created an application to install appimage applications. My application name is Happim. (Happim stands for Handle Appimage)

Works perfectly in ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

After installing happim, What all you need to do is to 1. launch happim by click the icon, 2. Type your appimage application name. 3. Select your preferred icon and appimage file through gui, 4. Click install. Now, your favorite appimage's icon will be available among your installed programs. You can add to favorite by right clicking and selecting 'Add to favorite'.

Free to use. Available in github.

Ensure the necessary packages have been installed.

Install prerequisite:

```
sudo apt -y update && sudo apt -y install python3 python3-pip python3-tk python3-pil python3-pil.imagetk xclip xsel libfuse2; pip3 install pyperclip
```

Download and install from github

```
git clone https://github.com/suramuthurs/Happim.git
cd Happim
python3 install.py
```

Go through my readme.md in github for the solution in case if it doesn't work